# ie7 preserve whitespace on dynamically injected text

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function init(){
  document.getElementById('test2').innerHTML = '1       2';
}
</script>
<style type="text/css">
#test{
  white-space:pre;
}

#test2{
  white-space:pre;
}
</style>
<title></title>
</head>
<body onload="init();">
<div id="test">
1       2
</div>
<div id="test2"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is an example page showing my problem. I have two divs. Each has this text **'1    2'** with white-space. The only difference is that one is injected dynamically and one is in the html itself.

If you open the above page in IE7, the text in div **test2** doesn't respect white space. How can i get the same behavior for the text that is dynamically injected??

P.S. My doctype is triggering standards mode on IE7.

Comment: Above is just a trimmed version of my problem. In the actual problem scenario, that string value is coming from a text-area that the user can enter any text in. So, The net required result is to preserve all newlines,spaces etc.

Comment: `innerHTML` is just broke. See eg. http://www.quirksmode.org/bugreports/archives/2004/11/innerhtml_and_t.html. Set the `data` property on a `Text` node to inject text content properly (or branch code to `textContent`/`innerText`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried substituting white space with `&nbsp;`

Alternatively, you could try `innerTEXT` instead of `innerHTML`

Comment: I dont want to get into modifying that string. Above is just an example. In the actual scenario, that string value is coming from a textarea that the user inputs his text in.

So I want to preserver newlines,spaces etc.

Comment: Hrm. Thats an interesting question. I'll look into it also. Might be useful to know in the future. Have you tried `white-space:pre-wrap;`?

Comment: Also try innerTEXT instead of innerHTML. Supposedly that preserves whitespace.

Comment: white-space:pre-wrap; doesnt work either. will try using innerText.

Comment: innerTEXT works fine on IE7. Going to accept this answer as edl mentioned it in the comments.